# Items(emojis) got tilted with display: grid;

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

So i was testing the display: grid; input to learn it (it was my first time hearing about it), i tried it and for the most part it worked just fine (the column and row input). the problem comes with the items inputs (that are emojis because the person in the video also used emojis), the emojis were tilted to the side instead of standing straight while in the video they were perfectly normal.

Also, how do i make the items css affect the emojis and not the background only?

[image]

```
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 500px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 200px;
    place-items: center;
}

i {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}



<div>
    <div class="grid">
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
            <i></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have placed your emoticons between italic tags <i>. What did you expect? Try wrapping your emojis in `div`'s or `p`'s, for example.

Comment: This has nothing to do with grid. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by 'how do i make the items css affect the emojis and not the background only'?

Comment: @Vitor Oliveira Are you asking how to make the emojis bigger?

Comment: Yes, i want to know how to make the emojis bigger.

Comment: @A Haworth I just want to make the emojis bigger.

Comment: @Vitor Oliveira If you want bigger emojis, you can just adjust the font-size of the wrapping element.

Comment: @Thomas thanks the emojis actually got bigger